# Python | Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: python, operating-system, scandir, google-cloud-shell, listdir

Running the follwoing script via GCP shell:

```py
def unpack_model(model_path, uploaded_filename):
    """ unpack uploaded zip/rar file """
    name, file_type = os.path.splitext(uploaded_filename)
    filename = "model{}".format(file_type)
    os.rename(os.path.join(model_path, uploaded_filename),
              os.path.join(model_path, filename))
    Archive(os.path.join(model_path, filename)).extractall(model_path)
    os.remove(os.path.join(model_path, filename))
    if 'main.py' not in os.scandir(model_path):
        copydata(os.path.join(model_path, name), model_path)
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(model_path, name))
```

I get the follwoing error:

```sh
if 'main.py' not in os.scandir(model_path):
[Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/app/data/u200315145936ca6bbd1163d/model/m200315153650d8f7069fc0b/model'
```

I have tried os.listdir() gives me the same error. Everything is ok, when the script runs on my local computer.

Anybody can help with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore symbolic by follow_symlinks=False
Example:

```
def get_directory_size(self, directory):
    total_size = 0
    for entry in os.scandir(directory):
       if entry.is_file():
          total_size += entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
       elif entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
          total_size += get_directory_size(entry.path)
    return total_size
```